# WebScraping: Get nested element in HTML Table

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am new to webscraping and got stuck on getting nested html element tag in a table, here is the html code I get from the url http://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=+Leisse&country=FR:

```html
<table class="restable">
   <tr>
      <td colspan=6 style="text-align: right;"><small>1 records found for "col de la Leisse"</small></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Feature class</th>
      <th>Latitude</th>
      <th>Longitude</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><small>1</small> <a href="/3003758/col-de-la-leisse.html"><img src="/maps/markers/m10-ORANGE-T.png" border="0" alt="T"></a></td>
      <td><a href="/3003758/col-de-la-leisse.html">Col de la Leisse</a><br><small></small><span class="geo" style="display:none;"><span class="latitude">45.42372</span><span class="longitude">6.906828</span></span></td>
      <td><a href="/countries/FR/france.html">France</a>, Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes<br><small>Savoy &gt; Albertville &gt; Tignes</small></td>
      <td>pass</td>
      <td nowrap>N 45° 25' 25''</td>
      <td nowrap>E 6° 54' 24''</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="tfooter">
      <td colspan=6></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This is the code for only one row to make things simple, but in my case I iterate over each row and check if the text of `<td>` element equal to a target value, if true I **scrape** the value of `<span>` element with class `longitude` and `latitude`. In my case I want to get the row with value `Col de la Leisse`
Here is my code: (not good)

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.findAll('table')[1] # second table
rows = table.find_all('tr')
target = "Col de la Leisse"
longitude, latitude = 0
for row in rows:
    cols=row.find_all('td')
    # I am stuck here...
    # if cols.text == target:
         # ...
```

Result:

```
longitude = 6.906828
latitude = 45.42372
```

Comment: Please, provide the result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use `:has` and `:contains` to ensure row has an `a` tag element with your target string in.

```
target = 'Col de la Leisse'
rows = soup.select('.restable tr:has(a:contains("' + target + '"))')
for row in rows:
    print([item.text for item in row.select('.latitude, .longitude')])
```

You can of course separate out `.latitude` and `.longitude` if you think they will not both be present, or if can occur in different order

Comment: yes but those are coordinates in minutes/second, the ones i want are in `<span class="latitude">45.42372</span>`, but before that I need to make sure that the target variable exist in my row

Comment: Thanks, and to make sur for that `td` element I have my target I add `if cols.text == target ` ?

Comment: or do you expect the .text to equal a specific value?

Comment: something like bottom version?

Comment: sorry but I will explain again ^^, in the `<a>` we have some texte there: "Col de la Leisse", and my `target ="Col de la Leisse"`, then if the html text match my target then I go look for longitude and latitude.

Comment: updated. You can of course separate out .latitude and .longitude if you think they will not both be present, or if can occur in different order

Comment: Thank you @QHarr, after updating my bs4 from 4.6 to 4.7 it worked !